# Convert seconds to W,D,H,M format in JAVA

Tags: java, seconds, time-format

I have time in seconds i want to convert it into a format like 6w 3d 9h 5m . Can someone please provide a method which can do this task. Thanks :)
w=weeks
d=days
h=hours
m=minutes

I have tried the below code but i dont get weeks using

```
int day = (int)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);        
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds));
long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds));
System.out.println("Day :"+day+" Hours :"+hours+" Minutes :"+minute);
```

Comment: I dont get weeks in this case . Also found that i cant get weeks using TimeUnit

Comment: @Mizan: please put it into the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int seconds=98765410;
int weeks = (int) (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds) / 7);
int days = (int) (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds) - 7 * weeks);
long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(days) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(7*weeks);
long minutes = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) * 60);
System.out.println(weeks+"w "+days+"d "+hours+"h "+minutes+"m");
```

Will print out:

```
163w 2d 2h 50m
```

Comment: I tried this .. Its not giving correct results , Week is always 1 . Thanks :)

Comment: Just tried, with 604801 it says that you have 1 week and that with 1209602 you have 2 weeks, it's working

Comment: tried with 98765410 i get 163w 2d 27386h 50m . Can you please help ? thanks

Comment: Now it works for me, i just forgot to subtract days from hours.

Comment: `163w 2d 2h 50m` is the correct one, i tested it and with my snippet the output is right, check if the seconds you set are `98765410`

Comment: ok but 163w 2d 2h 50m = 23539800 seconds ... The output is not correct. Actually i get seconds from a method this the the amount of time user has entered in the format w d h m .

Comment: I think your "conversion from w d h m to seconds" method is not correct, check it

Answer (score 3):

this will give you:

```
1w 4d 10h 20m
```

there should be more elegant way, but this works:

```
long s = 987654l;
        final long M=60,H=60*M, D=24*H, W=7*D; 
        long w = s/W;
        s%=W; 
        long d = s/D;
        s%=D; 
        long h = s/H;
        s%=H; 
        long m = s/M;

        System.out.printf("%dw %dd %dh %dm",w,d,h,m);
```